# How to determine which form was brought to front by clicking it?

Tags: c#, forms

I have an application with a Panel containing children Form objects. When I click one of the children Form it brings to front. I would like to know which one is in front now...
I've looked in event list but cant find proper event form my purpose :(

These methods doesn't work:

```
    protected void OpenedFileForm_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("enter");
    }

    protected void OpenedFileForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("click");
    }

    protected void OpenedFileForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("activated");
    }

    protected void OpenedFileForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("mouse click");
    }

    protected void OpenedFileForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("shown");
    }
```

[image]

```
        OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        openFile1.Filter = "TXT Files|*.txt|RTF Files|*.rtf";

        if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
           openFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {

            switch (Path.GetExtension(openFile1.FileName))
            {

                case ".txt":
                    txtForm childTXT = new txtForm();
                    this.childForms.Add(childTXT);
                    childTXT.Parent = this.mainPanel;              
                    childTXT.richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);                                               
                    childTXT.Show();
                    break;
            }


        }
```

Comment: I click the form, it is brought to front, but none of my methods are called.

Comment: @Rotem Nope, this one doesn't work too :( These children Forms are not MDI children of main Form. They are set this way: childForm.Parent = mainPanel; Where mainPanel is Object of System.Windows.Forms.Panel class.

Comment: I don't understand how that's even possible :o

Comment: Please add code which shows a complete example of your scenario.

Comment: @Sirtarius Could you also post `setMainForm()`? I didn't know this scenario was possible without MDI.

Comment: @Rotem `setMainForm()` is my method. It just save reference to main Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `Form.Activated` Event?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.80).aspx

Edit:

If you are in an MDI application, you might need to use `MdiChildActivate` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildactivate.aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried. I've edited my post to show which methods I've already used.

Answer (score 1):

This code can only work when you set the Form.TopLevel property to false.  Which makes it turn into a child control, almost indistinguishable from a UserControl.

This has many side-effects, for one there is no notion of "front" anymore.  The Z-order of child controls is determined by their position in their parent's Controls collection.  And it affects the events it fires, Activated and Deactivated will never fire.  Furthermore, the Form class was designed to be a container control, it doesn't like taking the focus itself.  Its child controls get the focus, the Form class doesn't have any use for focus.  Which is why the Enter, Click and MouseClick events don't fire, they are events that require focus.

Long story short, what you are trying to do doesn't make a wholeheckofalot of sense.  If it is strictly the Z-order you want to fix then write an event handler for the MouseDown event:

```
    void OpenedFileForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var frm = (Form)sender;
        frm.BringToFront();
    }
```

You could add frm.Select() to get the Enter event to fire, but only do that if the form doesn't contain any focusable controls itself.  Do note that there is evidence that you don't assign the events correctly in your code.  The Shown event *does* fire.  It is also important that you set the FormBorderStyle to None, the title bar cannot indicate activation status anymore.

Comment: Thx for explanation how it works inside. I was afraid that it's something like that :/ Anyway I think standard MDI approach will save me from other, future problems, so I'll just use MdiParent property instead of this Panel attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this! Thx for help everyone. You gave me a hint to think about equity of my strange MDI idea where Panel is parent for other Forms. I Removed SplitContainer containing Panel and just did standard MDI application, where Forms are MDIChildren of main Form.
        childTXT.MdiParent = this;

Comment: I'm still very interested in your previous attempt. You mean to tell me that the child forms were clipped to the bounds of the panel? I can't recreate a similar situation.

Comment: Yup. And it worked quite good until I reach this point. I pretty shure I didn't use any extra operations to achieve it. But I'm new in C# and WindowsForms programming so I could do something accidentally.